# How can I remove certain public folder from meteor build?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I am keeping all my bower components in `public/bower_comonents` and I want to remove `public/bower_comonents` from my meteor build.

How can I remove certain folders like `public/bower_comonents` from my meteor build?

Comment: Is adding them to a package an option? If so, you can make it `debugOnly`.

Comment: @DavidWeldon is it possible to keep PolymerJS like bower components in package ? i think HTML import will fail

Comment: Do you have a folder called "public/bower_comonents" or do you have a folder called "public/bower_com**p**onents"?  Misspelling it may be the source of your problem.